# C ++ error: a expected initializer before [function name]

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I am refreshing my self on C++ (have not did it since school) and I wrote a simple program just to mess around. My problem is when I compile the program it chokes stating 
    "error: expected initializer before 'stringThing'"
is there a reason why this is doing this? I know this may be a noob question so I checked stackoverflow and could not find any relevant questions that gave me a answer.

*I am using GNU GCC compiler

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void string stringThing (string shiftdir, string &teststring)
    {
        if (shiftdir == "right")
        {
           teststring = teststring >> " " >> "Bit Shifted right";
        }
        else
        {
           teststring = teststring << " " << "Bit Shifted left";
        }
    }
int main()
{

    string test;

    cout << stringThing("right", "I have done a ") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the sort of question that is answered not through random five-minute Googling, but by [learning C++ from a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This incorrect syntax is not taught in any C++ book.

Comment: For anyone who may have simply forgotten the `=` sign as an assignment operator before the function call, see my Q&A here: [error: expected initializer before ‘myFunction’ in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73504318/4561887)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type for `stringThing` must be either `void` *or* `string`, not both. You also must include `<string>`, if you want to use string.

Since you want to output the return value of `stringThing()` in `main`, I guess it should be

```
std::string stringThing (std::string shiftdir, const std::string &teststring)
```

But then, you must also return a string from your function

```
if (shiftdir == "right")
    return teststring + " " + "Bit Shifted right";
else
    return teststring + " " + "Bit Shifted left";
```

for example.

Your parameter `std::string &teststring` won't work with your `const char*` argument. So either declare it as a copy by value `string` only, or better `const string&`.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the _out_ parameter? I seriously doubt the intention is to return anything but `void`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This "out" parameter won't work anyway with the const char* rvalue. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

#### Return type is … funky

What is:

```
void string stringThing (string shiftdir, string &teststring)
```

?

Get rid of the first `string`. Your function returns nothing.

So, simply:

```
void stringThing(string shiftdir, string &teststring)
```

---

#### Inclusion missing

You will also need to `#include <string>` — in some scenarios you may get "lucky" and have it implicitly included by `<iostream>`, but don't rely on it.

Comment: Also, `#include <string>` would be a good thing to do, regardless of whether it's included in `<iostream>`.